# StackOverflowError error with maven package

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a Scala class that contains a method with has 1000 or so if-else conditions(there is no simple pattern that can be used to combine this, all conditions are very much different in nature).

```
    val a = "some string"
    if(a.contains("xx")){
      "aa_xx"
    }
    else if(a.contains("yy")){
      "121_Some random string"
    }
... and so on about 1000's conditions
```

When trying to build a jar using maven I am getting a StackOverflowError.
Tried to build with custom xmx values for maven but still seeing the same error.

```
[ERROR] error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Types$$anonfun$47.apply(Types.scala:4579)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Types$$anonfun$47.apply(Types.scala:4579)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType1(TypeComparers.scala:319)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType(TypeComparers.scala:278)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.retry$3(TypeComparers.scala:520)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.fourthTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:547)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.classOnRight$1(TypeComparers.scala:460)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.thirdTryRef$1(TypeComparers.scala:464)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.thirdTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:478)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.secondTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:450)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.firstTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:411)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType2(TypeComparers.scala:552)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType1(TypeComparers.scala:320)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType(TypeComparers.scala:278)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the stack size with `-Xss` ?

Comment: @HaraldGliebe where can I configure that?

Comment: `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xss10m" mvn package`

Comment: If your source code is repetitive enough to crash the compiler, then maybe improve your code. I can't rightfully believe that this code can't be written in a saner way. Who seriously maintains a file with thousands of these checks that should have been a simple map?

Comment: I just posted for an example purpose and there are other logical conditions which contain many AND as well OR checks and some don't have AND it is impossible to use map so the choice is left with many if-else and this is kind of data aggeration logic from other resources.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 1000 `else-if` statements. Use a loop.

```java
// Java example
final String[] SUBSTRINGS = { "xx", "yy" };

for (String sub : SUBSTRINGS) {
    if (a.contains(sub)){
        "aa_" + sub
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like increasing Xss param for `scala-maven-plugin` solved the issue

```
   <jvmArgs>
        <jvmArg>-Xss4m</jvmArg>
      </jvmArgs>
```